# How to deploy flink snapshot jar to private maven repository?

Tags: maven, apache-flink

I have build an snapshot version of Flink and want to deploy it to my private nexus repository. I try to add following configuration in pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id> botech-common-release</id>
            <name> Botech Common Release</name>
            <url> http://192.168.3.249:8081/repository/botech-common-release/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>botech-common-snapshots</id>
            <name>Botech Common Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://192.168.3.249:8081/repository/botech-common-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Then run 'mvn deploy' command. Unfortunately, maven still try to deploy snapshot of Flink into  official repository:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy
> (default-deploy) on project force-shading: Failed to deploy artifacts:
> Could not transfer artifact
> org.apache.flink:force-shading:jar:1.12-20210110.113153-389 from/to
> apache.snapshots.https
> (https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots): Failed
> to transfer file
> https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/flink/force-shading/1.12-SNAPSHOT/force-shading-1.12-20210110.113153-389.jar
> with status code 401 -> [Help 1]

How to change the target snapShot repository of Flink ?

Answer (score 0):

add the same configuration to the pom of force-shading module